# Search for mail in Sent Items, by date and subject with wildcard, from Excel

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I need to search for mail in Sent Items, sent on current date and with subject as "Task Completed". Sometimes Subject may have additional text like Task Completed on 07/01/2017 or Task Completed 01/09/2017.

I found this Outlook VBA code, which displays found mail. I want the code to run in Excel with wildcard search options and open an Excel file.

I tried to search the subject with wildcard "`*`", like "Task Completed`*`" and "Task Completed on & Format(Date, "dd/mm/yyyy")" for which I got an syntax error/compile error

```
Sub Test()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As NameSpace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Integer

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
i = 1

For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
    If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Task Completed on 07/01/2017") <> 0 Then
        olMail.Display
        i = i + 1    
    End If    
Next olMail

End Sub
```

I am using Office 2010.

Comment: let me know if you tried the code in my answer below, and if it worked for you

Comment: Thank You sir, I tried your code, but I do not want to store any email id or sent date in excel. Actually I want to run a Macro in excel searching for outlook mail with Task Completed. I want your code to run in excel. Please help me how to do it or is there any way I can call this code in an window.open event in excel?

Comment: 'Sub Test()
Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As NameSpace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Outlook.MailItem
Dim i As Integer
Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)
i = 1
For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
If InStr(olMail.Subject, "Task Completed") And InStr(olMail.SentOn, Format(Date - 1, "mm/dd/yyyy")) <> 0 Then
olMail.Display
i = i + 1
End If
Next olMail
End Sub'

I edited some code and it is working fine in Outlook, but can this code be used in excel VBA editor and run from there?

Comment: I ran this code from Excel, and I just add these 2 lines of code to show an example of how to display the matching emails result. What do you want to do from Excel once there is an email match ? Try the edited code in my answer

Comment: Sir, I have a Workbook_Open code, I want the Workbook_Open to run all the macros when there is an email match without displaying the mail.

Comment: why on `Workbook_Open` ? i think it should be something you control, like in a module called by a button. Once you have this Excel workbook open, this code will not run anymore the way you want it to be

Comment: Thank you very much Sir for your help and as you suggested, I will put a button and run this code instead of 'Workbook_Open'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to loop through all items in ***Sent Items*** folder, including Calendar events you may have, use the `Dim olMail As Object` (instead of `AS Outlook.MailItem`).

To look for "Task Completed" string somewhere in the email's title, use `If olMail.Subject Like "*Task Completed*" Then` (adding the wildcard `*` before and after the searched string).

I've added 2 lines of code, that output all matching emails to your worksheet in Column A and Column B.

**Code**

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()

Dim olApp As Outlook.Application
Dim olNs As Namespace
Dim Fldr As MAPIFolder
Dim olMail As Object
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer

Set olApp = New Outlook.Application
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail)

i = 1
For Each olMail In Fldr.Items
    ' check if mail subject contains "Task Completed" in the email title
    If olMail.Subject Like "*Task Completed*" Then
        'Range("A" & i).Value = olMail.Subject ' <-- output email name to column A
        'Range("B" & i).Value = olMail.SentOn ' <-- output email sent date to column B
        olMail.Display ' show email through Excel
        i = i + 1
    End If
Next olMail

End Sub
```