# Retroactive link between outlook and vba

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I’m currently working on an access Vba program in order to automatically write mails to people. However we chose to still press ‘Send’ in Outlook manually (in case there are possible issues, so we can control the mail beforehand).

Is there a way to have a link in the other direction, as in, when pressing the Send button in Outlook, getting the email address of the person back in excel? (The goal would be to make a ‘history’ sheet in order to keep track of which mails were actually sent and to whom)

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Yes. A simple case is shown below. This is bare bones demonstrating the actions you requested.

Public variable, `addressSent`, holds the To address. A boolean test on mail sent (by @Rory) tests for the mail item having been sent and calls a function, by @Dwipayan Das, that opens a specified Excel file, and writes the `addressSent` to cell A1 in sheet1.

You can tinker with this to fit your purposes. E.g. Adapt the function to accept a file name as parameter.....

Taking a note from @ashleedawg's book: remember to include a  xlApp.Quit line so Excel is not left hanging.

I believe your question wanted to go from Outlook to Excel so this is the application that you will have created that needs closing.

So in Outlook goes the following code:

Put this in a standard module:

```
Option Explicit
Public addressSent As String
Dim itmevt As New CMailItemEvents

Public Sub CreateNewMessage()

    Dim objMsg As MailItem

    Set objMsg = Application.CreateItem(olMailItem)

    Set itmevt.itm = objMsg

    With objMsg

        .Display
        .To = "somebody@mail.com"
        .Subject = "Blah"

        addressSent = .To

        .Send

    End With

End Sub

Public Function openExcel() As Boolean 'Adapted from @Dwipayan Das

    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim sourceWB As Object
    Dim sourceWS As Object

    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With xlApp

        .Visible = True
        .EnableEvents = False

    End With

    Dim strFile As String

    strFile = "C:\Users\User\Desktop\Delete.xlsb" 'Put your file path.

    Set sourceWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strFile, , False, , , , , , , True)

    sourceWB.Activate

    sourceWB.Worksheets(1).Range("A1") = addressSent

End Function
```

Then in a class module called `CMailItemEvents`, code from [@Rory](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/326733-check-see-if-outlook-email-sent-excel-vba.html), put the following:

```
Option Explicit

Public WithEvents itm As Outlook.MailItem
Private Sub itm_Close(Cancel As Boolean)
   Dim blnSent As Boolean
   On Error Resume Next
   blnSent = itm.Sent
   If Err.Number = 0 Then
      Debug.Print "not sent"
   Else
      openExcel
   End If
End Sub
```

References:

1. [Check to see if an Outlook Email was sent from Excel VBA](https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/326733-check-see-if-outlook-email-sent-excel-vba.html)
2. [How can I use Outlook to send email to multiple recipients in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985261/how-can-i-use-outlook-to-send-email-to-multiple-recipients-in-excel-vba)
3. [How to open an excel file in Outlook vba code](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/4e84f0de-2270-4176-a46f-c6891b45d693/how-to-open-an-excel-file-in-outlook-vba-code?forum=exceldev)
4. [Create a new Outlook message using VBA](https://www.slipstick.com/developer/create-a-new-message-using-vba/)
5. [Run code after item sent](http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/archive/index.php/t-21349.html)

Comment: d'oh, you *just* beat me to it! I'm gonna post mine anyway, it goes the opposite way, pulling from Outlook into Excel, the last x items sent.

Comment: @ashleedawg Note ScreenToGif  now in production :-)

Comment: haha, no that's saved for "click this, then click this..." kind of answers :)

Comment: so, your sub is triggered by an items being sent, correct?

Comment: That is the idea. I didn't want to capture if the mail didn't actually go. It was a minimal effort job, but hopefully useful, as OP could have shown more sens de l'effort. You are so polishing a masterpiece aren't you? :-)

Comment: OMG I give up on my second half.  Yours is better anyway!  ...I can get the last mail item in a folder with `.GetLast` but neither `.GetPrevious` nor `.GetNext` are giving me the item before that, and `.Sort "[SentOn]"` doesn't seem to make a difference whether ascending or descending.  I could loop through the collection... but I'm tired of staring at it, so I won't!  (The privileged of working for free!)

Comment: I guess, but conveying the right code at the right time is half the battle. :)    ...besides nobody really "writes" code anymore, do they?  I consider more of "reworking existing solutions".  Get the ol' [punchcards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Punched_card#/media/File:IBM_card_storage.NARA.jpg) out, now **that's** coding. (except it probably wasn't called that at the time.)

Answer (score 0):

Just a quick 'n dirty function that will run in Excel/Access/Word and returns the email address from the most recent item in the `Sent Items` folder (no error handling, etc):

```
Function LastSentEmailAddress() As String
'Requires reference: "Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library"

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application, olMail As Object
    Set olApp = New Outlook.Application 'create Outlook object
    Set olMail = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI").GetDefaultFolder(olFolderSentMail).Items.GetLast

    LastSentEmailAddress = olMail.Recipients(1).PropertyAccessor.GetProperty( _
            "http://schemas.microsoft.com/mapi/proptag/0x39FE001E") 'get email addy

    olApp.Quit 'close Outlook

End Function
```

---

***A Note about working with Outlook objects from Excel:***

When working with applications such as Excel it's important to make sure the application object is properly `.Quit` / `.Close`'d when finished with them, (and to `Set` all objects to `Nothing`), otherwise there's a risk of inadvertently having multiple instances running, which can lead to memory leaks, which leads to crashes and potential data loss.

To check if there is an existing instance of Outlook, use this function:

```
Function IsOutlookOpen()
'returns TRUE if Outlook is running

    Dim olApp As Outlook.Application

    On Error Resume Next
    Set olApp = GetObject(, "Outlook.Application")
    On Error GoTo 0

    If olApp Is Nothing Then
        IsOutlookOpen= False
    Else
        IsOutlookOpen= True
    End If

End Function
```

<sub>(Source: **[Rob de Bruin](https://www.rondebruin.nl/win/s1/outlook/openclose.htm)**)</sub>

---

### More Information:

- MSDN : [Items.GetLast Method (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869214(v=office.14).aspx)
- MSDN : [Items Object (Outlook)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/VBA/Outlook-VBA/articles/items-object-outlook)
- MSDN : [Obtain the E-mail Address of a Recipient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/outlook-vba/articles/obtain-the-e-mail-address-of-a-recipient)
- Office.com : [How to disable warnings about programmatic access to Outlook](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/i-get-warnings-about-a-program-accessing-email-address-information-or-sending-email-on-my-behalf-86cc5ece-379e-45e3-b8eb-3fefba09946b?NS=OUTLOOK&Version=16&SysLcid=1033&UiLcid=1033&AppVer=ZOL160&HelpId=olmain11.chm553714171&ui=en-US&rs=en-US&ad=US)
- MSDN : [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012(v=office.12).aspx) (Book Excerpt)
- MSDN : [Check or Add an Object Library Reference](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/check-or-add-an-object-library-reference)
- Stack Overflow : [VBA to search an Outlook 2010 mail in Sent Items from Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41565313/8112776)